# How do I add a class into a hasMany relation in Jenssegers / Laravel / Mongo?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add a hasMany relation from my Project class to my Version class (Projects have many Versions).

I have these:

My Project class -

```
namespace App;

use Version;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    public function versions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Version');
    }
}
```

My Version class -

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Model;

class Version extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nickname'];

    public function project() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }
}
```

And in a route -

```
public function createVersion(Request $request)
{
    $projectID = $request->input('projectID');
    $version = $request->input('version');

    $project = Project::where('_id', $projectID)->first();

    $version = new Version();
    $version->projectID = $projectID;

    $version->nickname = $version['nickname'];

    $project->versions->save($version);

    return $version;

}
```

I am getting the error - `Class 'Version' not found` - and it points to Model.php.

Am I missing adding a "use" somewhere, or am I missing something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the class `Version` under the `App` namespace.

For that reason you must use

```php
public function project() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

in your `Project` class.

Comment: Hi GiamPy, I have tried both `use App\Version` and `use Version` in my Project class. Both result in the same error.

And to add - my route has `use App\Version` and it works fine to get passed `$version = new Version();` - the error occurs on `$project->versions->save($version);`

Comment: Try using `return $this->hasMany('App\Version');`

Comment: Yes that seems to work although I am now running into further problems. Likely not related to this so I will accept your answer.